# Bonobo Git Server - Windows Authentication - Git interactions

Tags: git, bonobo

I have installed the Bonobo Git Server using the Windows Authentication method: http://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/

The front end works - I can both authenticate via Internet Explorer without any credentials required, and I can also authenticate using my UPN or domain account and password in Firefox.

The problem is when I try and do an Initial commit push for a repository I wish to setup - I get the message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.url.com/git_server/repo.git/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 500

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 1):

So, maybe it was just because it was the end of the day yesterday, but I have come back to this and made it work quite easily. Not exactly sure of the fix, but the one change I made was setting the following line in both Web.config's to the same value:

```
    <add key="GitServerPath" value="https://git.url.com/git_server/" />
```

I then used the following remote url for git push and pulls:

```
https://git.url.com/repo.git/
```

Previously I think I had tried using the url detailed in the web interface, which points to the virtual directory of the git server component of the windows authentication Bonobo server configuration.